# Why does Devorim 28:20 start in the 3rd person and end in the 1st person?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment

In [Devorim 28:20](https://www.sefaria.org/Deuteronomy.28.20?lang=bi&aliyot=0)  it says

> The L-RD will let loose against you calamity, panic, and frustration
> in all the enterprises you undertake, so that you shall soon be
> utterly wiped out because of your evildoing in forsaking Me.

The possuk starts off in the third person “The L-RD will let loose” and ends in the first person “because of your evildoing in forsaking Me.”

Why? It should have ended “because of your evildoing in forsaking Him.”

Comment: I wonder if this is the only case in the Torah (or the Tanakh in general) where the narration changes person.

Comment: +1 this is a great question

Comment: Who said "Me" is capitalized?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the [רקנאטי on the parsha](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Recanati_on_the_Torah%2C_Ki_Tavo.11?lang=he) where he addresses and answers the issue by offering two different approaches:

> ישלח יי' בך את המהומה וגומר. מפני רוע מעלליך אשר עזבתני. כבר פירשתי כי משה ידבר מפי הגבורה והיא האומרת ישלח יי' מפני **אשר עזבתני ולכן לא אמר אשר עזבת את יי' כמשמעות הפשט** אם יהיו דברי משה אך משה ידבר מפי השכינה **כי פיהו כפיה**. והר"ר אלעזר מווירמש"א ז"ל כתב כי **כנוי עזבתני שב למשה רבינו ע"ה** כי הוא עומד ורואה כשישראל לוקין על עונותיהן ואומר למזלם של ישראל זה יש לכם מפני **שעזבתני ולא שמעתם לאזהרותי**. וראיה לדבריו מצאתי במדרש

1. Since Moshe was speaking as an agent of Hashem and the point in this part of the pasuk is being presented to Bnei Yisroel as if Hashem is doing the speaking OR...
2. He quotes R. Elazar of Worms (*the author of Sefer HaRokeach - see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eleazar_of_Worms) and [here](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%90%D7%9C%D7%A2%D7%96%D7%A8_%D7%9E%D7%92%D7%A8%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%99%D7%96%D7%90)*) as writing that the word עזבתני (*you have abandonded me*) actually refers to Moshe warning Bnei Yisroel that they will be punished whenever they abandon him by not heeding his warnings (about performing the mitzvos given by Hashem).

Also see [הכתב והקבלה on Devarim 28:15](https://www.sefaria.org.il/HaKtav_VeHaKabalah%2C_Deuteronomy.28.15.1?lang=he), who agrees in a general sense with the first answer above and expands a bit especially where he writes:

> אבל כאן **שמדבר משה בלשון נסתר**, ידבק ה' בך, **ישלח ה' בך**, הנה לא נתמנה להשמיע הדברים כאילו יוצאים מפי הקב"ה בלשון מ"ב, רק להשמיע בלשון נסתר, ומשה הוא המדבר, וזה מפי עצמו. והתבונן שבכל דברי התוכחה נאמרו בלשון נסתר, **רק פעם אחת אמר כאילו יצא מפי הגבורה עצמו, מפני רוע מעלליך אשר עזבתני** (פ"ך) והיה מן הראוי לומר ג"כ בלשון נסתר "עזבת את השם", ונראה שהתכוין משה בזה לעורר את דור אנשי הברית בשמעם שדבריו הם בלשון נסתר, פן יטעה אחד מהם לחשוב שהדברים נאמרו מדעת משה ולא שמעם מפי הש"י, **לכן בחר במלת עזבתני כמו שיצא מפי הגבורה, ומזה ידונו על שאר הדברים ויבינו כי כולם מוצא פי השם המה**

*(Loose translation) "It seems that Moshe intended to wake up the people of the covenant who had (until now) heard his words in the third-person, lest any of them err and think that the words originated from Moshe's mind and were not heard by Moshe from Hashem, therefore he chose the word עזבתני as if it is now coming directly from the mouth of The Almighty"*